# Index Error in python

Tags: python, encryption

I am new to programming, and I am trying to write a Vigenère Encryption Cipher using python. The idea is very simple and so is my function, however in this line:

```
( if((BinKey[i] == 'b')or(BinKey[i+1] == 'b')): )
```

It seems that I have an index problem, and I can't figure out how to fix it.
The error message is:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I tried to replace the `i+1` index by another variable equal to `i+1`, since I thought that maybe python is re-incrementing the `i`, but it still won't work.

So my questions are:

1. How to fix the problem, and what have I done wrong?
2. Looking at my code, what can I learn to improve my programming skills?
3. I want to build a simple interface to my program (which will contain all the encryption ciphers), and all I came up with from Google is pyqt, but it just seems too much work for a very simple interface, so is there a simpler way to build an interface? (I am working with Eclipse Indigo and pydev with Python3.x)

The Vigenère Encryption function (which contains the line that causes the problem) is:

```
def Viegner_Encyption_Cipher(Key,String):
    EncryptedMessage = ""
    i = 0
    j = 0
    BinKey = Bin_It(Key)
    BinString = Bin_It(String)
    BinKeyLengh = len(BinKey)
    BinStringLengh = len(BinString)
    while ((BinKeyLengh > i) and (BinStringLengh > j)):
        if((BinKey[i] == 'b')or(BinKey[i+1] == 'b')):
            EncryptedMessage = EncryptedMessage + BinKey[i]
        else:   
            EncryptedMessage = EncryptedMessage + Xor(BinKey[i],BinString[j])
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
        if (i == BinKeyLengh):
            i = i+j
    return EncryptedMessage
```

This is the `Bin_It` function:

```
 def Bin_It(String):
    TheBin = ""
    for Charactere in String:
         TheBin = TheBin + bin(ord(Charactere))
    return TheBin
```

And finally this is the `Xor` function:

```
def Xor(a,b):
    xor = (int(a) and not int(b)) or (not int(a) and int(b))
    if xor:
        return chr(1)
    else:
        return chr(0)
```

Comment: That's almost unreadable Python code. I suggest you to follow PEP8 style guide!

Comment: I agree. Specifically, extraneous parentheses and large first letters for normal variables is confusing.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to achieve with `Bin_It`?

Comment: @Eric

Bin_it returns a string that contain the binary value of a string.
Hope it makes sence.    
     Example:
          Bin_It('aaa')
          returns : '0b11000010b11000010b1100001'

Comment: @user1815939: I know what it does. My questions is on what you think that result is good for.

Comment: @Eric: I am trying to do a viegner encryption, where the encrypted message will be the Xor of the original text, and the key, and in order to do that, i wrote the Bin_It function to get the binary values of the message and the key.

Comment: @hamza: You realize python has a bitwise xor operator, right? `ord(Key[i]) ^ ord(String[j])` does what you want, for the right values of `i` and `j`

Comment: @Eric: Actually no, i didn't realize that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your while condition, you are ensuring that `i < len(BinKey)`. This means that `BinKey[i]` will be valid, but `BinKey[i+1]` will not be valid at the last iteration of your loop, as you will then be accessing `BinKey[len(BinKey)]`, which is one past the end of your string. Strings in python start at `0` and end at `len-1` inclusive.

To avoid this, you can update your loop criterion to be

```
while BinKeyLength > i+1 and ...:
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either change

```
while ((BinKeyLengh > i) and (BinStringLengh > j)):
```

to

```
while ((BinKeyLengh > i-1) and (BinStringLengh > j)):
```

or change

```
if((BinKey[i] == 'b')or(BinKey[i+1] == 'b')):
```

to

```
if((BinKey[i] == 'b') or (BinKeyLengh > i-1 and BinKey[i+1] == 'b')):
```

This will avoid trying to go into `BinKey[BinKeyLength]`, which is out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

> Looking at my code, what can I learn to improve my programming skills?

Looping over an index is not idiomatic Python. It's better to loop over the *elements* of an iterator where possible. After all, that's usually what you're interested in: `for i in...` is often followed by `my_list[i]`.

In this example, you should use the built-in function [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (or [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) if your code is lazy, though this [isn't necessary](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) in Python 3), which gives you pairs of values from two or more iterators, and stops when the shortest one is exhausted.

```
for key_char, string_char in zip(BinKey, BinString):  # takes values sequentially from
                                                      # BinKey and BinString
                                                      # and binds them to the names
                                                      # key_char and string_char
    # do processing on key_char and string_char
```

---

If you really *must* do a `while` loop on an index, then put the test the other way around so it's clearer what you're doing. Compare

```
while len(BinKey) > i and len(BinString) > j:  # this looks like len(BinKey) and
                                               # len(BinString) are varying and you're
                                               # comparing them to static variables i and j
```

with

```
while i < len(BinKey) and j < len(BinString):  # this looks like you're varying i and j
                                               # and comparing them to len(BinKey) and len(BinString)
```

Which better communicates the purpose of the loop?

---

Finally, the clause

```
if (i == BinKeyLengh):
    i = i+j
```

doesn't seem to do anything. If `i == BinKeyLength` then the `while` loop will stop in a moment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error, as Python interpreter says, is that you accessing invalid array positions.
In order to solve this, unlike it's being said, you should change your code to

`while (BinKeyLength > i+2 and ...):`

This is because in the last step, BinKeyLength = i+2, then i+1 is BinKeyLength-1, which is the last position of your array.

Concerning your programming skills I recommend you two things:

- Be the code. Sounds mystic but the most important thing that is missing here is figuring out which indices numbers are used.
- As it has been said by rubik, follow some style guides like [PEP8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).